# Error running C++ file using Visual Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner to Ubuntu and Linux. I'm attempting to run just a simple hello world code and every time I run the C++ code in visual studio, it doesn't actually run, it opens to a new file called settings.json (which is empty).
[image]

If anyone can help me sole this problem that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not Visual Studio, btw.

Comment: OT:  `c++` is not a scripting language. The term "run c++ files" is not technically correct. You don't run c++ files at all. You compile them into object files which a linker may (depending on your commands) turn it into an executable application that then you can run.

Comment: Can you show your `tasks.json` and `launch.json`

Comment: Visual Studio Code doesn't come with a compiler. You need to have one installed and have VS Code set up to use the compiler. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw.

Comment: This is probabably a better link for linux: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

Answer (score 2):

> I am a beginner to Ubuntu and Linux.

### Read about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

#### It is favoring the command line and combination of simple tools

(e.g. in a [command pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) for your [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) in some [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)). A successful command (e.g. [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html), used to copy files, or [g++(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html), a C++ compiler, or [man(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) to read documentation, and [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or [less(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) to inspect a file, or [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) to list them) often stays nearly silent when successful; see [intro(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/intro.1.html). Be aware of [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (see also [intro(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)). Remember that some parts of your C++ code could be generated (by [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) tools such as [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/), [swig](https://swig.org/), or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), or your own [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html), [Python](https://python.org/) or [GAWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script, or some other C++ program, etc...). See also [Linux From Scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/). Every [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (except `/sbin/init`) is started by [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) with [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). See also [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), [pstree(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) and [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Your C++ compiler could be [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (or else [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/)). Be sure to read the documentation on [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), and about your C++ preprocessor (perhaps [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)). Try  `g++ --version` then `g++ --help` in some terminal emulator.

If that command works, compile your `HelloWorld.cpp` with all warnings and debug info, so run in your terminal `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g  HelloWorld.cpp  -o HelloWorld`; you later run the obtained [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) using `./HelloWorld` in the same terminal (read about the [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) in [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and try the [printenv(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html) command).

Of course, you'll use some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) or [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-code_editor) (e.g. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [vim](http://vim.org/) or [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or [geany](https://www.geany.org/)). Be sure to take some time to read its documentation. You'll configure them to run some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool. You surely want to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system, such as [git](https://git-scm.com/).

And you'll need a debugger such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Later, you'll want to use some build automation tool to drive your compilation commands (of several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) and the linking command (part of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)). Consider for your build automation using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or many others.

Read of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and some good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) (and [reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)). Be aware that C++ is a very difficult and complex programming language (see its spec [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)).

You could enjoy reading some [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). Study for inspiration the source code of existing open source C++ programs (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/)), such as the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just run the file. The simplest way is to open the command terminal and find where your file is located, the path that it is stored in and type in g++ fileName.cpp, make sure to name it with a cpp extension.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't output anything to the terminal though, i'm not sure why. Could it be something with the location of my G++? I have my c++ code stored in my Documents folder and g++ is located here: g++: /usr/bin/G++/usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz

Comment: Use cd to navigate to your file, so if your file is in users/bin/helloWorld.cpp: Do the following: cd users[enter] cd bin[enter] g++ helloWorld.cpp use ls to list all the files in the directory, this is starting to become UNIX knowledge not c++ anymore.

Comment: I cd into the documents folder and then entered "g++ HelloWorld.cpp"

Comment: Check where your helloworld.cpp is located, also don't forget to add a main function.....

Comment: The hello world cpp file is located in the documents folder, I cded into documents and typed ls, then it shows "HelloWorld.cpp" so i ran that command above^ and it did not output anything. I have a main function in the program

Comment: Yep can you show me your main program, because you need to cout << "Hello World!" << endl in your main for it to work, also don't forget return zero, if this answer helped you please upvote it.

Comment: @AnthonyHorner You also need to run the created executable.

Answer (score 1):

It is **possible** to  compile and run C/C++ programs from Visual Studio Code.

To compile and run C/C++ programs from Visual Studio Code *(vscode)* you need to install `C/C++ Compile Run extension` from ***danielpinto8zz6*** in  Visual Studio Code.

After installing the `C/C++ Compile Run extension`  press `F6` to compile and run C/C++ Program.

Hope it helps !